# Adding z value vertices from a point layer to a line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, elevation, vertices, z-value

I created a point layer from a line using **Vector geometry/Extract vertices** in the **Processing toolbox**.

The purpose is to extract the elevation from a DEM into the points corresponding the vertices and then into the line layer.

I managed to get the elevation values on the points but I can't really figure it out how to add the values to the vertices in the line layer.

My final objective is to export a LineString geojson file containing the x, y, z values. 
There might be easier ways but I couldn't find any so far.

P.S. I created a z value field in the line layer, just need to copy the values from one layer to another.

[image]

Comment: I think you can achieve it using the GRASS tool `v.drape`. Give a look to this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238100/3d-linework-from-dem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get Z-values directly from your raster using [Menu Processing / Toolbox / Drape (set z value from raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#drape-set-z-value-from-raster). This will output a new line layer: a copy of your initial line with z-Values for each vertex:

[image]