# Associate height information from DTM/ DSM to polyline

Tags: qgis-3, dem, line, building-heights, rooftop-building

I have both DTM and DSM files of a city and would like to propagate this information to the building outlines. What I am hoping to do is to get the average height of the building outline and get this information associated to the features themselves. That way, I could make flat extrusions up to the roof line. Then do this once more for the roof lines within, so I can further model the roofs in Rhino. Does anyone know how to get this done? And is there a tutorial available on this?

Comment: Start with Drape geoprocessing tool.

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/412531/88814